# $\omega t$ scaling in plot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the response of a pure inductor circuit, but the scale I want to use is $\omega t \;(100\pi t)$, but the default scaling is linear. Here is my code.

```
Vs = 200; L = 0.1;
pulse = Vs (UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[t - Pi] - UnitStep[t - Pi] + 
     UnitStep[t - 2 Pi]);
i = Vs*t/ L;
i1 = i (UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[t - Pi]);
i2 = (-Vs*(t/(100 Pi ) - Pi)/L + Vs*Pi/L) (UnitStep[t - Pi] - 
     UnitStep[t - 2 Pi] );
Plot[{pulse, i1, i2}, {t, 0, 3 Pi}, Exclusions -> None]
```

Here is the output I'm getting

[image]

The peak value of current should come 10 amperes.

Comment: Is this a *Mathematica* issue? *Mathematica* here is working as expected.

Comment: I want to scale the x-axis to 100pi times.

Comment: You mean you want the 2, to be replaced by 200pi, while keeping the functions unchanged?

Comment: yes, that's what I want.

Comment: Easiest way might be to just rescale the `t` value.  Since you don't have `pulse`, `i1`, and `i2` defined as functions, then you need to do a replacement rule workaround.  But this does what you want I think `Plot[Evaluate[{pulse, i1, i2} /. t -> t/(100 Pi)], {t, 0, 300 Pi^2}, 
 Exclusions -> None]`